# How can I call a methode from the MainWindow without making an instance of it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a method in my Mainwindow, i want to call this method in an other usercontrol.
I dont use a static method because my MainWindow is not Static, and I can't make it static.
So I figured out to use this, but I dont know what comes behind the AS and I dont know if I can put a method is VAR?
I also can't make another MainWindow instance because that gives me a Stackoverflow exception. 
How can I solve this?

```
var myMethode= mainWindow.FindName("MyMethode") as (should be a methode);
if (myMethode!= null) 
{  
    //My code
}
```

Comment: but the code wont work because i cannot make an instance of my mainwindow because of the StackOverFlow, so there must be another opstion :)

Comment: If your method is not static because it uses fields of MainWindow, you must create an instance. If your method doesn't use fields or params or ... of MainWindow, why not make it static?

Comment: @Martin because when i make it static it wont work, it gives me an error, on abject reference is required for  the non static field , methode or property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a static method on a class that is not static.

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Foo.DoSomething();
    foo.DoSomethingElse();
}

public class Foo
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething");
    }

    public void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse");
    }
}
```

But wouldn't it be a better solution to pass the `MainWindow` as a parameter into the User Control? So the user controls knows to which window it belongs and can access a function on it? (even better to declare an interface for this and pas the interface around).

This would look like:

```
public interface IWindow
 {
     string SomeWindowActivity();
 }

 public class MyUserControl
 {
     public IWindow Window { get; set; }

     public void SomeActionOnUserControl()
     {
         string data = Window.SomeWindowActivity();
     }
 }

 public class MainWindow : IWindow
 {
     MyUserControl MyUserControl { get; set; }

     public MainWindow()
     {
         // Link the UserControl to the Window it's one. This can be done trough the 
         // constructor or a property
         MyUserControl.Window = this;
     }

     public string SomeWindowActivity()
     {
         // Some code...

         return "result";
     }
 }
```

Comment: I'am working with a Kinect application. And the whole code of the Kinect is in the MainWindow, i cant put it in an other usercontrol, because i,am using the mouse and skeltal tracking all the time.

Comment: what did u mean by passing it as a parameter, can u show me an example ?

Comment: when i make it static it wont work, it gives me an error, on abject reference is required for the non static field , methode or property?

Comment: This because you are accessing instance data from a static function. As other answers mentioned, that's not possible.

Comment: but there must be a way, the point is i have a SettingsPage usercontrol, and i want to show or hide a canvas(this canvas is located on the mainwindow). In my settingspage i want to say yes show me the canvas or no dont show me the canvas.

Comment: Use the pass as parameter example you see above.

Comment: MyUserControl.Window = this, doesn not work, it askes me to create a new instance ?

Comment: Do you have a reference to your user control? Does your user control has a Window property definedIs it of the correct type?

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx)

```
((MyMainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Method()
```

You don't need to make MainWindow singleton in your case, you have access to it from Application.Current singleton

```
Application.Current.MainWindow
```

Hope this helps

Comment: So this i call in my Usercontrol, the point is i have a SettingsPage usercontrol, and i want to show or hide a canvas(this canvas is located on the mainwindow).
In my settingspage i want to say yes show me the canvas or no dont show me the canvas.

Comment: ok, can you write a  method ExpandConvas(bool isExpand) in your MainWindow, and call that method from usercontrol ((MyMainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ExpandConvas(true)

Comment: MyMainWindow is the concrete type of your MainWindow, type and not instance, just put your MainWindow type there

Comment: I assume the Methode() should be my ExpandConvas, but it is not shown in the list. it is public in the MainWindow, what could this be ?

Comment: please drop me your window definition, it should be something like this class ... : Window, as I said before, you should convert Application.Current.MainWindow to type of concrete window

Answer (score 0):

Short unswer: you can't. You want to call a instance method, you need to have an instance.

The fact that MainWindow is not static does not prevent you from defining static methods in it, as long as those methods do not use other instance members, so if it a helper method, you can define it static and call from other place, it might a good idea to refactor it out of MainWindow class then.

If it's a nonstatic method, you claim you don't want to create second instance of MainWindow, why not call it on first instance then, by passing it to your control?

Also, if creating another instance of MainWindow gives you stackoverflow, maybe it's because you just did some recurrent call with this method, and it can be fixed?

Comment: I'am working with a Kinect application. And the whole code of the Kinect is in the MainWindow, i cant put it in an other usercontrol, because i,am using the mouse and skeltal tracking all the time, so i cant refactor right ? its being used in the mainwindow all the time.